# Create multiple bookmarks on iPad/iPhone home screen at once

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I have a list of about 10 bookmarks I want to create as iOS home screen icons. Are there quick ways to do this?

And is there a way to edit them once they're created?

Answer (score 1):

I would **nope** and **nope**, at least without jailbreaking.

You can only create bookmark one by one and name them as you want.

Once they are created, the only way to rename them is to create a new one and delete the old one.

Jailbreaking allows to rename any apps, so I think web apps, too. I'm not sure about editing home screen web apps.